# Android HtppGet URL connection

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão httpget do android para o php, eu fiz todo codigo php conectando ao mysql mas começa dar erro a partir após do "urlConnection = ..."

```
protected String doInBackground(String... String username = (String) arg0[0];
String password = (String) arg0[1];
String urlString = "https://splitfz.000webhostapp.com/login.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
StringBuffer chaine = new StringBuffer("");

URL url;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    url = new URL("https://splitfz.000webhostapp.com/login.php?username="+ username +"&password="+ password +"");

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();

    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

  InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

    int data = isw.read();
    while (data != -1) {
        char current = (char) data;
        data = isw.read();
        System.out.print(current);
    }
    this.statusField.setText("deu certo");
} catch (Exception e) {
    this.statusField.setText("deu erro");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

return chaine;
    }

Comment: Coloque o erro que é exibido no logcat

Comment: Bem Vindo Amigo! 
Por favor, sugerimos que realize um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site e veja [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! 
Assim, facilita a comunidade a te ajudar! 
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o problema esteja neste trecho do código:

```
url = new URL("https://splitfz.000webhostapp.com/login.php?username="+ username +"&password="+ password +"");
```

Note que você está passando um `https` na `URL`, no entanto você está utilizando `HttpURLConnection` quando deveria ser um `HttpsURLConnection`

Por exemplo:

```
url = new URL(https_url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

Você pode ler sobre os métodos relacionados de cada um deles em:

[HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

[HttpsURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)

Se precisar de um exemplo, isto pode lhe ajudar:

[Java HttpsURLConnection example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-https-client-httpsurlconnection-example/)

Comment: Bem observado! +1